# What does that mean, a black hole "rotates"?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, event-horizon, singularities, frame-dragging

A black hole has:

- a mass
- electrical charge
- angular momentum?

In the inner, there is a singularity, all the mass, collapsed to one point.
The event horizon is surrounding that singularity.

How can a point rotate? What is meant when speaking about a one-dimensional thing rotating?

Comment: *"How can a point rotate?"* - why do you ask about a point singularity in this context?  From the Wikipedia article ["Ring singularity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_singularity), find:  *"A ring singularity or ringularity is the gravitational singularity of a rotating black hole, or a Kerr black hole, that is shaped like a ring."*

Comment: Similarly, an electron also has intrinsic angular momentum (spin) even though it too is a point particle.

Comment: Up voted Lewis Miller but I would like to undo....